# MONO on RedHat - .net application not working

Tags: mono, redhat

I need your help for porting .dot net application on RedHat OS with MONO.

I have done below steps:

1. I took the .net build and deployed in /var/www/html/
2. used Ngnix for reverse proxy to browse my application.

And I could able to see the login.aspx page and able to login into system,
but when its directing to next level, it shows below error.

> Server stack trace:   at
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost.VirtualDirectoryExists
>   (System.String virtualPath, System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest worker)
>   [0x00001] in <4704eaeeb7224e0caaf0606fd809885e>:0   at
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost.ProcessRequest
>   (Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder responder) [0x00030] in
>   <4704eaeeb7224e0caaf0606fd809885e>:0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost:ProcessRequest
>   (Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder)   at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch)
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost:ProcessRequest
>   (object,byte[]&,byte[]&) Exception rethrown at [0]:   at (wrapper
>   xdomain-invoke) Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost:ProcessRequest
>   (Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder)   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.ApplicationHost:ProcessRequest
>   (Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder)   at
>   Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder.Process () [0x00060] in
>   <4704eaeeb7224e0caaf0606fd809885e>:0

I am not sure why this is error is occurring, please let me know.

Comment: Every line of Mono is open source. So when there is no clear documentation anywhere, you should try to read its source code at GitHub to understand the reason.

Comment: works for me in Ubuntu, maybe a RedHat problem?